# " invalid date ‘TZ="UTC" @’ " error while using "date" command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, date, timezone, prediction

I'm trying to run some bash script I got on the internet, but it keeps spiting out error:

> date: invalid date ‘TZ="UTC" @’

Refering part of code:

```
while [ $(date --date="TZ=\"UTC\" @$var2" +'%D') == $(date --date="TZ=\"UTC\"" +'%D') ] ; do
```

At first, there were more issues, but I managed to resolve one ("[: ==: unary operator expected") by using double brackets ("[[" and "]]").

After bracket change:

```
while **[[** $(date --date="TZ=\"UTC\" @$var2" +'%D') == $(date --date="TZ=\"UTC\"" +'%D') **]]** ; do
```

Also, I read that this script should run without sudo. I was executing it as root but even when I didn't, it did not run because of a permission error that I also couldn't resolve.

My thinking is that it may be a problem with `--date` that can't read entire string but only to "@" ("@" included). I don't have much experience in bash, and so I was looking through forums and sites, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. Can anyone help and maybe explain what exactly is going on inside this while statement?

Answer (score 1):

`TZ=UTC` isn't part of the date string, it's an environment variable you set outside the `date` command:

```
while TZ=UTC [ "$(date --date "@$var2" +'%D')" = $(date +'%D') ] ; do
```

Comment: Thank You for help!

I have one more line to change in similar way. Should I again set somehow `TZ=UTC` or, since it is environment variable I don't have to?   


Code:

OUTDATE=`date --date="TZ=\"UTC\" $START_TIME" +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

Comment: When you write `variable=value command` the variable assignment only lasts during that one command, so you need to repeat it for each command. You can also do `export TZ=UTC` by itself, then it will apply to all following commands.

Comment: Seems like you need to read a tutorial on environment variables in shell scripts.

Comment: After changing to `while TZ=UTC [ "$(date --date "@$var2" +'%D')" = $(date +'%D') ] ; do` the script still gives `date: invalid date ‘@’` error.

Comment: What is the value of `$var2`?

Comment: var2=`echo $PREDICTION_END | cut -d " " -f 1`

Comment: PREDICTION_END=$(/usr/local/bin/predict -p ${1} | tail -1)

Comment: The error message indicates that it's empty.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of your script to debug it. This will show all the commands with the variables expanded.

Comment: I have no idea what `/usr/local/bin/predict` does.

Comment: The emptines of `/usr/local/bin/predict` will be a topic for diffrent problem then. I think I know what it can be but It's not related to script. Now I only need to know how to change  `OUTDATE` variable.  Will: OUTDATE=`TZ=UTC date --date="$START_TIME" +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` makes sense?

Comment: Yes, you can put `TZ=UTC` inside the backticks or `$()`

Comment: OUTDATE=`$(TZ=UTC) date --date="$START_TIME" +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
?

Comment: No, `OUTDATE=$(TZ=UTC date --date="$START_TIME" +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)`

Comment: What's wrong with the way I did it in my answer? Then you don't have to repeat the TZ setting for each call to `date`?

Comment: Doing it your way only makes sense if you want to use different timezones in each use of `date`.